# When your web page can go to sleep

Tags: javascript, jquery, sleep

I have a web page, using jQuery and javaScript, and I would like to find out if and when to put the page to sleep.  As a number of the tasks are background processes I need to put them to sleep if nothing is happening on the page.  i.e. the user is working on another screen or not on his PC full stop

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set a timer that is reset on several events based on user interaction with the page.  A very basic example would be:

```
var timeout;    
var awake = true;
function resetTimer ()
{
    awake = true;
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function () 
    {
        awake = false;
    }, 36000); // Set the timer for 5 minutes
}
document.documentElement.onfocus = document.documentElement.onmouseover = function ()
{
    if (!awake)
        runRequests(); // Replace any stale data
    resetTimer();
}
```

In the requests for the data, you would check the state of the `awake` variable and if it's false, return out of the function.  When the user interacts with the page again, the necessary data would be refreshed and the `awake` variable set to true again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a timeout function would work.  It would have to check periodically whether any events you care about have occurred, and so decide whether to put the page "to sleep."